# Ticketing System

Tags: python, sql

I am thinking to create a simple desktop application.

Only two computers will be used, client side and admin side. (Both connected on the same network).

**Purpose of the app**

Data to be used from client side:

- Date & time
- User
- Product
- Ready (yes or no)

**Usage**

- Send data from client side to admin.
- **admin** receives data from **client**, inspects it, ticks it as `good to go` or `not ready`.
- **Client** will be able to see their sent data and see if admin has approved it as `good to go`

Simple as that.

I'll need to store the information, somewhere, maybe like SQL?

**Question**

What would be a suitable language and software to use to create this sort of ticketing app?

I am thinking tkinter and mysql.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use an open source Kanban board like https://wekan.github.io/

I think with Kanban you can map almost every workflow.
I think in your case you have columns / steps like: incoming, todo, in progress and ready.